# QTableView data disapears by opening another QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtableview

I have an application developed in Python using PyQt4, In which i used QTableView to display a reports.
when i open one report window with QTableView it shows the result properly.
If i open another report window with QTableView it shows the result properly.

Now both the windows are displaying the data in there QTableViews.

Now the issue is, When i select the 1st report window the data in it is disappearing.

Can anyone tell me exactly whats wrong i am doing.

Comment: We can't say anything without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you are using same instance of `QtSql.QSqlDatabase`  for all the views you create.